# In particle physics/SM, how to demonstrate that dimension of length is 1/energy?

Tags: particle-physics, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

In particle physics/Standard Model, using $\hbar=1, c=1$, how to demonstrate that dimension of length is 1/energy?

More generally, how to find dimension of a given operator, for example the covariant derivative?

Comment: Do you understand what the dimensions of $\hbar c$ are when we don’t set these constants to 1?

Comment: This is energy . distance. But my question is more general, for any choice of operator

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#%22Natural_units%22_(particle_physics_and_cosmology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\hbar=c=1$ then $\hbar c$ is dimensionless. However, it also has dimensions of energy times length, so the dimension of length must be the inverse of that of energy, so that the units cancel.

Comment: Thank you @bemjanim

Comment: No problemo my guy